# Vim appimage can't run on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: linux-ubuntu, vim9

Vim has a official [AppImage](https://github.com/vim/vim-appimage/releases/tag/v9.0.0813) (cool). But I can't run it on Ubuntu 22.04. I suppose that some dependencies are lost. My problem is that I can't identify what exactly are. I see the terminal output when I try run it but I can't understand.

I change the permission of binary and in the terminal I run it with `./Gvim...`

The output of `./GVim-v9.0.0813.glibc2.15-x86_64.AppImage`:

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gvfs/libgvfscommon.so: undefined symbol: g_task_set_name
Failed to load module: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gio/modules/libgvfsdbus.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gio/modules/libgiognomeproxy.so: undefined symbol: g_task_set_name
Failed to load module: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gio/modules/libgiognomeproxy.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gio/modules/libgiognutls.so: undefined symbol: g_byte_array_steal
Failed to load module: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gio/modules/libgiognutls.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gvfs/libgvfscommon.so: undefined symbol: g_task_set_name
Failed to load module: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gio/modules/libgioremote-volume-monitor.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gio/modules/libgiolibproxy.so: undefined symbol: g_task_set_name
Failed to load module: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gio/modules/libgiolibproxy.so

(gvim:4990): Gtk-WARNING **: 11:22:50.942: Theme parsing error: gtk-dark.css:1427:23: 'font-feature-settings' is not a valid property name

(gvim:4990): Gtk-WARNING **: 11:22:50.946: Theme parsing error: gtk-dark.css:3264:25: 'font-feature-settings' is not a valid property name

(gvim:4990): Gtk-WARNING **: 11:22:50.947: Theme parsing error: gtk-dark.css:3726:23: 'font-feature-settings' is not a valid property name

(gvim:4990): Gtk-WARNING **: 11:22:51.169: Theme parsing error: gtk-dark.css:1427:23: 'font-feature-settings' is not a valid property name

(gvim:4990): Gtk-WARNING **: 11:22:51.173: Theme parsing error: gtk-dark.css:3264:25: 'font-feature-settings' is not a valid property name

(gvim:4990): Gtk-WARNING **: 11:22:51.174: Theme parsing error: gtk-dark.css:3726:23: 'font-feature-settings' is not a valid property name

(gvim:4990): Gtk-WARNING **: 11:22:51.287: Could not load a pixbuf from icon theme.
This may indicate that pixbuf loaders or the mime database could not be found.
**
Gtk:ERROR:../../../../gtk/gtkiconhelper.c:494:ensure_surface_for_gicon: assertion failed (error == NULL): Failed to load /usr/share/icons/Pop/16x16/status/image-missing.svg: Could load the load module of images: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gdk-pixbuf-2.0/2.10.0/loaders/libpixbufloader-svg.so: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librsvg-2.so.2: undefined symbol: pango_attr_insert_hyphens_new (gdk-pixbuf-error-quark, 5)
Vim: Caught deadly signal ABRT
Vim: Finished.
Aborted (`core' generate)
```

Comment: I don't think you'll find useful help here for this issue, as it's more about AppImage and running on recent Ubuntu rather than vim itself (I imagine you'd run into similar issues with other AppImages too), so maybe consider filing an issue at https://github.com/vim/vim-appimage/issues to report what you're seeing.

Comment: It also doesn't work for me on my Void Linux machine, [albeit with some different errors](https://gist.github.com/arp242/5b5412c8fb8706e29299a879557adab8). Like filbranden said, I think this question is probably better suite on the vim-appimage issue tracker as it mostly requires "Appimage expertise" rather than "Vim expertise".

Comment: Thanks to both of you. In the issues section I found a [similar problem](https://github.com/vim/vim-appimage/issues/32) and a hint but for a partial solution.

Answer (score 0):

Execute the official AppImage of Vim in Ubuntu 22.04 (and derivates, I suppose) is simple, but it isn't easy to understand what happened when you try to execute the first time (at least for me). This answer is a help for novice linux users but is a partial answer.

The binary is called `GVim-v9...appimage`, and is a binary has the two 'forms' of Vim: terminal and GUI (gvim).

In Ubuntu 22.04, it seems, the dependencies are old or maybe incomplete (please look this [issue](https://github.com/vim/vim-appimage/issues/32) in the official repo of Vim AppImage). When you try to execute the binary called `GVim-v9...appimage` you are executing the GUI version of Vim, maybe for GTK dependencies, I don't know, you can't run GVim.

But you can execute the terminal Vim with that same binary, whereby you can have the vim's last version in Ubuntu 22.04. The info are in the [readme](https://github.com/vim/vim-appimage) of official repository of Vim AppImage.

For you to get terminal Vim you must make a symbolic link of the binary that you downloaded (here with the version 9.0.0813):

```
ln -s GVim-v9.0.0813.glibc2.15-x86_64.AppImage vim.appimage
```

Now, in terminal execute `./vim.appimage` and you have the last version of Vim, but, terminal Vim, that is the way that I use Vim, but if you are seeking to execute GVim you have to report this issue in the official repo of Vim AppImage, maybe there can help you.